# how can i build tensorflow model in specific shape?

Tags: tensorflow

```
BATCH_SIZE = 32  # ADVISED NOT TO CHANGE THIS

N_PAST = 10  # DO NOT CHANGE THIS

N_FUTURE = 10  # DO NOT CHANGE THIS

SHIFT = 1 

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=5,
                               strides=1, padding="causal",
                               activation="relu",
                               input_shape=[None, 1]),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu"),

        tf.keras.layers.Dense(N_FEATURES)
    ])
```

I build a time-siries forcasting model but i can't understand how to handle this.

which layer should i use to make this available?

```
Model input shape must be (BATCH_SIZE, N_PAST = 10, N_FEATURES = 1)

Model output shape must be (BATCH_SIZE, N_FUTURE = 10, N_FEATURES = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

the **batch_size** is not specified in the model.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=5,
                               strides=1, padding="causal",
                               activation="relu",
                               input_shape=[N_PAST,1]),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(N_FUTURE)
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify batch_size in input layer. Just change input shape as follows:

```
input_shape=[N_PAST,1]
```